# relational algebra to get unique pairs

Tags: relational-algebra

Let's say we are given this table of the relation Person(name, hobby)

```
name   hobby
bob    hockey
alice  basketball
mary   cricket
mark   basketball
rick   snowboarding
andy   hockey
```

How would I use relational algebra to find the hobby that had only one person had.

It should give me

```
hobby
cricket
snowboarding
```

My ATTEMPT:

$R1 := \rho_{P2}(Person)$

$R2 := R1 \bowtie_{P2.hobby = P1.hobby \text{ } AND \text{ } P2.name <> P1.name} R2$

$R3 := \pi_{hobby} (R2)$

Comment: Could you use aggregating functions?

Comment: Just these ----Union

----Intersection

----Difference

----Selection

----Projection

----Cartesian Join

----Theta join

----Natural join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more carefully defined $\theta$-join and then set difference:

$$R1 := \rho_{name1/name,hobby1/hobby}(Person)$$
$$R2 := Person \bowtie_{(hobby=hobby1) \land (name \neq name1)} R1$$
$$R3 := \pi_{hobby}(Person) \setminus \pi_{hobby}(R2)$$